# Setting a PHP cronjob for multiple timeframes

Tags: php, cron

I need to set a PHP script to run once every 5 minutes between 8pm and 9pm, nightly.

My understanding of `cronjob`s is that they run on a fixed time interval such as once every day, once every week etc.

What I need is some way of running regular cronjobs (every 5 minutes) within a specific time frame (8pm to 9pm). The script that runs is the same script.

## Ideas

- Run one PHP script at 8pm via `cronjob` ad loop the code inside a timer loop so the script runs constantly (with `sleep`) for the hour. This seems to me to be a poor solution; inefficient.
- Run a secondary cronjob trigger by the first so at 8pm run a cronjob to then run a second cronjob to run every 300 seconds to call the script. *Is this even possible?*
- Install multiple duplicate cronjobs at each required time interval, so one at 20:00, one at 20:05, one at 20:10, 20:15, etc. This is not very DRY programming.
- Run the cronjob every 5 minutes 24/7 and exit the PHP script early when the time does not fall between 8pm and 9pm . This seems wasteful/inefficient as 95% of cronjob script triggers will simply exit.

None of these ideas seem to really efficiently fit the bill. Are there choices I have missed?

## To be absolutely clear:

I use cronjobs already but they run on single-interval timeframes. I have read all about cronjobs on here and elsewhere and can't find any guidance for multi-inteval time frames.

I am looking for something that runs within two time frames rather than simply one!

Question:
What method(s) can I use to run a standalone PHP script every 5 minutes between two timepoints (8pm and 9pm, in this case)?

Comment: `*/5 20 * * *` for cron time pos?

Comment: @treyBake wouldn't that run every 5 minutes forever after 8pm?

Comment: I think the last of your ideas is the best. You can leave the PHP script very quickly so it won't use many resources when it is just idling. PS: The [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/5_20_*_*_*) will tell you in words what something obscure like `*/5 20 * * *` actually does.

Comment: @Martin ahh thats kewl though, everyone learns and wins from this q :D

Comment: Correction -- I misunderstood the cronjob syntax; @treyBake yes your comment is correct. See the edit to my answer. I think you should add your comment with details as an answer `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical, that after posting this question I find a solution from [this useful link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

The answer being:

```
*/5 20 * * * /usr/bin/php /www/virtual/username/cron.php
```

This `*/5` runs every five minutes between the times of `2000` and `2000` + 1 hours. As [pointed out by Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828147/setting-a-php-cronjob-for-multiple-timeframes?noredirect=1#comment98321431_55828275) this means the final cronjob execution would be 2055.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware your updated comment above was actually also very close to the solution I found (but I have not tested this solution yet).

Comment: this runs every 5 minutes from 20:00 to 21:55.

Comment: When you say "8pm to 9pm", do you mean to include the whole 9pm hour? Because that's what this does. What are the first and last times you want it to run?

Comment: @Barmar ahhh, that's frustrating --but I think the client may not realise if it's not 9pm on the dot. In a perfect world the fist cronjob would run at 20:00 and the last cronjob would run at 21:00. I think for the sake of ease I can adjust our spec's.

Comment: @Barmar I could just add a second duplicate cronjob to run at 2100 only, I guess.

Comment: Yes. One should be `*/5 20 * * *` the other should be `* 21 * * *`